# Remove an item from Python list if the item's dictionary key has some value

Tags: python, list, dictionary, text-processing

I have a list of dictionaries.

```
for i, d in enumerate(test_list):
    print(i, d)

0 {'role': None, 'content': 'Closing the gap between actual and potential crop yields', 'bounding_regions': [{'page_number': 1, 'polygon': [{'x': 4.2076, 'y': 9.019}, {'x': 7.5767, 'y': 9.019}, {'x': 7.5767, 'y': 9.387}, {'x': 4.2076, 'y': 9.387}]}], 'spans': [{'offset': 3482, 'length': 56}]}
1 {'role': None, 'content': 'Increasing realized yields per area requires both increasing the maximum possible regional yield for a given crop in the absence of biotic or abiotic stress (yield potential [Yp];', 'bounding_regions': [{'page_number': 1, 'polygon': [{'x': 4.2066, 'y': 9.4723}, {'x': 7.6041, 'y': 9.4723}, {'x': 7.6041, 'y': 9.9493}, {'x': 4.2066, 'y': 9.9493}]}], 'spans': [{'offset': 3539, 'length': 179}]}
2 {'role': None, 'content': 'Downloaded from https://academic.oup.com/plphys/article/185/1/34/6149974 by guest on 16 June 2023', 'bounding_regions': [{'page_number': 1, 'polygon': [{'x': 7.9365, 'y': 2.8965}, {'x': 8.0406, 'y': 2.8965}, {'x': 8.0406, 'y': 7.9632}, {'x': 7.9365, 'y': 7.9632}]}], 'spans': [{'offset': 3719, 'length': 97}]}
3 {'role': 'pageFooter', 'content': 'Received August 14, 2020. Accepted October 3, 2020. Advance access publication 19 November 2020 VC American Society of Plant Biologists 2021. All rights reserved. For permissions, please email: journals.permissions@oup.com', 'bounding_regions': [{'page_number': 1, 'polygon': [{'x': 0.5499, 'y': 10.1762}, {'x': 4.8923, 'y': 10.1762}, {'x': 4.8923, 'y': 10.3865}, {'x': 0.5499, 'y': 10.3865}]}], 'spans': [{'offset': 3817, 'length': 222}]}
```

How can I remove an item from the list that has certain value for it's dictionary key.
For example, I want to remove the entire item number 3 from 'test_list' because it's dictionary key d['role'] == 'pageFooter'.

So the result would look like:

```
0 {'role': None, 'content': 'Closing the gap between actual and potential crop yields', 'bounding_regions': [{'page_number': 1, 'polygon': [{'x': 4.2076, 'y': 9.019}, {'x': 7.5767, 'y': 9.019}, {'x': 7.5767, 'y': 9.387}, {'x': 4.2076, 'y': 9.387}]}], 'spans': [{'offset': 3482, 'length': 56}]}
1 {'role': None, 'content': 'Increasing realized yields per area requires both increasing the maximum possible regional yield for a given crop in the absence of biotic or abiotic stress (yield potential [Yp];', 'bounding_regions': [{'page_number': 1, 'polygon': [{'x': 4.2066, 'y': 9.4723}, {'x': 7.6041, 'y': 9.4723}, {'x': 7.6041, 'y': 9.9493}, {'x': 4.2066, 'y': 9.9493}]}], 'spans': [{'offset': 3539, 'length': 179}]}
2 {'role': None, 'content': 'Downloaded from https://academic.oup.com/plphys/article/185/1/34/6149974 by guest on 16 June 2023', 'bounding_regions': [{'page_number': 1, 'polygon': [{'x': 7.9365, 'y': 2.8965}, {'x': 8.0406, 'y': 2.8965}, {'x': 8.0406, 'y': 7.9632}, {'x': 7.9365, 'y': 7.9632}]}], 'spans': [{'offset': 3719, 'length': 97}]}
```

Really appreciate your help in this matter.
Also, I intend to run this for thousands of text data, so some efficiency may also come into question.
Thank you

Comment: `[d for d in test_list if d['role'] != 'pageFooter']`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this will filter only one element satisfying the condition so its use cases are more narrow:

```
idx = next((i for i,x in enumerate(test_list) if x.get('role') == 'pageFooter'), None)
if idx: del test_list[idx]
```

but it is much faster in many cases than a list comprehension:

```
import timeit
setup = "test_list=[" + ",".join(f"{{'i':{i}}}" for i in range(10000)) + "]"
v_1 = "idx = next((i for i,x in enumerate(test_list) if x.get('i') == 50), None)\nif idx: del test_list[idx]"
v_2 = "[d for d in test_list if d.get('i') != 50]"
min(timeit.repeat(v_1, setup=setup, repeat=100, number=1)) #6.6530001276987605e-06
min(timeit.repeat(v_2, setup=setup, repeat=100, number=1)) #0.0006724879999637778
```

Edit:

Note that there are ways (a loop) to use the same methodology even without the restriction on the removal of only one element, but in general this will be more efficient only if on average the number of deletions will be very small.

Comment: Note that this does not actually filter anything; it directly deletes a single element satisfying the criterion from the original list ("destructive" solution).

Comment: yes @Amadan I probably used the wrong word :-)

Comment: Thanks, the speed up is definitely worth to try!

Answer (score 4):

You can use list comprehension:

```py
test_list = [d for d in test_list if d.get('role') != 'pageFooter']
```

Comment: Note that this does not delete anything; it creates a new list without all of the elements satisfying the criterion ("non-destructive" solution).

Comment: Thanks, this is simple and will try this one